# In Geometry Nodes, what is the easiest way to create a surface texture using an instanced object?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

Can anyone outline a potential workflow to creating this kind of object (where a texture is repeated on multiple sides) using geonodes?

[image]

I can easily do it by creating a diamond and then skinning it to the surface of my object using subdivide > mesh to points > instance on points:
[image]

But it doesn't work when the mesh isn't uniform and I'm not sure how to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the methods that can be used is UV sampling.

*Sample UV Surface* node arranges objects on UV coordinates of the mesh. You can use existing UV or do like this:

[image]

Comment: Whoa, my mind is blown a little.  I can't wait to tinker with this when I get back to work.  Can you share you project file, or show me what your starting geometry looks like?  I'm having a hard time following exactly what is going on there with the grid and the Sample UV Surface node.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't save it. The screenshot is clear, though. The geometry is subdivided cube with some deleted faces. Scale should be applied

Comment: OK I finally dug around with this and learned a lot from it.  Unfortunately, for my case, it is not elegant enough to work as a solution.  There is a strange overlap at every corner and I can't figure out how to finesse that.  This is a tough one for me because I used to use C4D and this kind of thing would be a snap using their Mograph tools (you just use an object cloner and assign your texture object to it with no overlap and viola!).  I'm hoping a more elegant solution will present itself, but I thank you again for helping to deepen my understanding of geonodes. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, since there are no more answers to this, for now I'm marking this as correct. I've been playing around with it more and although it does feel clunky, it is a solution nonetheless.  If there was a way to get the size of the face, and then mathematically set the number of vertices accordingly, that would be great.